# C# Copying Enumeration from one object to another

Tags: c#, enums

I have two very similar but not identical C# objects. I am copying the values from one class to another.

Each class has some properties that expose an enumeration type. The inside of the enumerations are the same but the names are different e.g.

```
public enum EnumA
{
 A,
 B
} 

public EnumA EnumAProperty
{
 get{ return enumA;}
}

public enum EnumB
{
 A,
 B
} 

public EnumB EnumBProperty
{
 get{ return enumB;}
}
```

I want to assign the value returned from EnumBProperty to EnumAProperty is this possible?

Comment: hmmm not sure if enum types are compatible in that way...

Comment: unless you assigned values to the enum members and got the value of EnumA and assigned that value to EnumB. Would that work?

Comment: `eNumb` – something so bad that it numbs its users to the pain of using it.  :-)

Comment: On a design note (and obviously not knowing your objects) - do the separate enums need to be defined in the object classes, or could you have a common enum in a separate static class, and have your objects use that?  That eliminates the parsing/maintenance/setting-a-non-defined-enum-value issues, if it is possible to do.

Comment: Wonko. I'm taking an object as a source and writing it to XML file using a .NET generated class that is very similar but not identical to the source object. The source object is from an external webservice that I don't have control over and the xml schema is also outwith my control. I'm just in the middle trying to glue the two together so I don'tthink I can adopt your idea on the common enum

Comment: Fair enough.  Glue code sometimes makes us do painful things... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do via casting but I would not recommend it as it is fragile — if any of the enum members are reordered or new items added the result may not be what you expect.

```
EnumAProperty = (EnumA) EnumBProperty;
```

Even worse with the casting is if you have items in your source enum with no equivalent in the destination — below there are more colours than shapes:

```
enum Color { Red = 0, Yellow = 1, Blue = 2 };
enum Shape ( Square = 0, Triangle = 1 };

Color color = Color.Red;
Shape shape = (Shape) color;
```

`shape` could end up with the value `2` even though this value is not defined.

Instead, I'd suggest you use a `switch` statement to map:

```
EnumAProperty = ConvertToA(EnumBProperty);

...

private static EnumA ConvertToA(EnumBProperty b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case EnumB.Flannel: return EnumA.HandTowel;
        case EnemB.Vest: return EnumA.UnderShirt;
        ...
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("b");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the ver important, but often overlooked, point that you can assign a value that isn't defined in the enum.

Answer (score 4):

Each `enum` member has a corresponding integer value.
By default, these values are assigned in ascending order, starting with `0`.

If the order of the items in the enums (and thus their numeric values) are the same, you can just cast the numeric value to `EnumB` to get the `EnumB` member with the same value:

```
 EnumBProperty = (EnumB)(int)EnumAProperty;
```

If not, you need to re-parse it:

```
EnumBProperty = (EnumB)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumB), EnumAProperty.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as both enum's of different types you can'not assign it directly.
You can define integer offset for an items so you can assign values through the integer value

```
public enum EnumA 
{  
 A = 0,  
 B = 1
}   

public enum EnumB
{  
 A = 0,  
 B = 1
}   

EnumBPropertry = (int)EnumAProperty
```

Comment: That's ok, until somebody changes the definition of the enum in one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could either cast it to an integer or convert it to a string and then do an Enum.Parse on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
EnumAProperty = (EnumA)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumA), EnumBProperty.ToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EnumBProperty = (EnumB)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumB), EnumAProperty.ToString());
```